# PHP image failing to do, well, anything

Tags: php, image

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
      or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

That should work, but is just showing a blank page. I have php-gd installed. Help?

Comment: Do you have GD2 installed? What warnings/errors does the page show, if you turn on error display?

Comment: Comment out the call to the `header` function to see if a PHP error was being hidden.

Comment: Hmm, the original example is [on PHP's doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php), so the code should work.

Comment: Something has to be happening.  What does your page source look like?

Comment: Neglected to restart after installing, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try some debugging steps:

1. Turn on error reporting
    
   `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`
2. Remove the `header()`
3. Remove the `@` from `@imagecreatetruecolor()`
4. See what errors you are receiving.

Comment: Forgot to restart what? Your server?